# Mocking laravel-echo with vitest and @vue/test-utils

Tags: laravel, jestjs, vuejs3, laravel-echo, vitest

I'm working on a Vue3 app in a Laravel/Vue/vite stack and using `laravel-echo` for pusher stuff. Some components are interacting with `Echo.private` or `Echo.notification` and I've thus far been unable to mock Echo to test it or if nothing else to prevent many errors when testing other aspects of the components. Example usage:

```
Echo.private(`user.${user?.id}`)
      .listenToAll((event, data) => {
        if (data?.data?.message) {
          adminMessagesStore.addMessage(data.data.message);
          scrollToBottom(bottomOfList.value);

          adminMessagesStore.getRecent();
        }
      });
```

In this case, I am using that code in the "onMounted" hook after fetching initial data.

My first instinct was/is to mock like so:

```
vi.mock('laravel-echo');
```

With that, I get the error `TypeError: default.private is not a function`. I then tried this:

```
const mockEcho = {
  private: vi.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  listenToAll: vi.fn(),
};
vi.mock('laravel-echo', () => mockEcho);
```

and get the error `Error: [vitest] There was an error when mocking a module. If you are using "vi.mock" factory, make sure there are no top level variables inside, since this call is hoisted to top of the file. Read more: https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mock`. I've mocked several third party dependencies without such issues (axios, @vueuse/core, my own custom composables or utilities).

Does anyone have experience with successfully mocking and testing `laravel-echo` with either vitest or jest and @vue/test-utils? The boostrap setup is boilerplate. These errors are occurring even with the simplest mounting tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, figured this out like so:

```
vi.mock('laravel-echo', async () => {
  const actual = await vi.importActual('laravel-echo');

  return {
    ...actual,
    default: {
      private: vi.fn(() => {
        return {
          listenToAll: vi.fn(),
        };
      }),
    },
  };
});
```

The mock was not actually mocking `private` or `listenToAll`, so had to partially mock and override the default property with expected mocked functions.